# multitouch issue (imageview lag)

Tags: android, imageview

If I click the button it works normally but when pressing more than 1 button the image view hangs for seconds before changing

My Code:

My Code:

```
   ArrayList<Integer> ids = null;
    ids=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ids.add(R.drawable.comp2);
    ids.add(R.drawable.comp3);
    ids.add(R.drawable.comp4);
    ids.add(R.drawable.comp5);
    ids.add(R.drawable.comp6);
    ids.add(R.drawable.comp7);
    ids.add(R.drawable.comp8);
    ids.add(R.drawable.comp9);
    ids.add(R.drawable.comp10);
    button a = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
   public void onclick{
   name()
    }
   int i =o;
   public void name() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                imageview.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if(i<ids.size()) {
                             imageview.setImageResource(ids.get(i));
                             i++;
                         }else i=0;
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They way you are doing is of no good. You are creating one thread and inside that thread you are changing `ImageView` src. I would suggest you to use [transition](http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-beginner-tutorial-part-88.html).
You can define it in xml as well as in dynamically using [code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html).